# Jquery DataTable: hide Paginator if rows are less than records per page

Tags: jquery, datatable

I use jquery datatable in page above table I have selector for records per page

```
<div id="NewsTable_length" class="dataTables_length">
<label><select size="1" name="NewsTable_length" aria-controls="NewsTable">
<option value="25" selected="selected">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select> records per page</label>
</div>
```

below table I have pagination

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pagination">
<ul>
<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">← 
<span class="hidden-480">Prev</span></a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">
<span class="hidden-480">Next</span> → </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to hide dataTables_paginate :

```
 $('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
```

in:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function () {
               },
```

when Total rows < NewsTable_length.selected

any suggestions?
thanks in advance,..

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm trying to do the same thing (hide the pagination controls if number of rows is less than the selected "records per page") but was thinking this would be possible via some configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ){
    if(oSettings.fnRecordsTotal() < 10){     
        $('.dataTables_length').hide();
        $('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
    } else {
        $('.dataTables_length').show();
        $('.dataTables_paginate').show(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you want to hide it based on the current length that the user has selected, you can change the hard-coded `10` to `oSettings._iDisplayLength`.

If you want to hide the pagination when you've filtered down the tableto 1 page, you can change the `oSettings.fnRecordsTotal()` to `oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
var oTable = $('#tableTxn').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "searching": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bSort": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "lengthMenu": [10, 20, 30],
        "ajax": {
            data: {  },
            "type": "post",
            "url": "",
        },
        drawCallback: function(settings) {
            var pagination = $(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_paginate');
            pagination.toggle(this.api().page.info().pages > 1);
        }
    });
```